# How to use IF OR & AND in excel formula

Tags: excel, if-statement, excel-formula

I am not a coder, but I'm trying to work on an excel sheet to make things more efficient at work. 
I have two formulas that I need to combine and I can't figure it out! please help. I am trying to put this on my T2 cell.

This is the first one. I basically want to say if O2, R2, and S2 =yes, OR if Q2, R2, and S2 =yes, then "yes" otherwise leave blank. This is what I figured out and it is working! 
`=IF(OR(AND(O2="YES",R2="YES",S2="YES"),AND(Q2="YES",R2="YES",S2="YES")),"YES"," ")`

However, If O2=NO and Q2=NO, then I want it to say No, otherwise leave blank. I have the two separate formulas but can't figure out how to combine. 
`IF(OR(AND(O2="NO", Q2="NO"),"NO", " ")`

I was thinking maybe I can do this: `=IF(OR(AND(O2="YES",R2="YES",S2="YES"),AND(Q2="YES",R2="YES",S2="YES")),"YES","NO")` the only problem with this is that it automatically fills a NO, even if the cells are blank. I want it to skip it if its blank. 
Link to spreadsheet image below:

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Test it first, then do the rest of the tests

```
If (AND(O2="NO",Q2="NO"),"NO",IF(AND(R2="YES", S2="YES",OR(O2="YES",Q2="YES")),"YES",""))
```

I have also grouped the (R2="YES", S2="YES") as you were checking this twice and you don't need to.

Answer (score 0):

Put it in the `else`

```
=IF(OR(AND(O2="YES",R2="YES",S2="YES"),AND(Q2="YES",R2="YES",S2="YES"));
"YES",
IF(OR(AND(O2="NO", Q2="NO"),
     "NO",
     " "))
```